# XSLT - Comparing preceding-sibling's elements with current's node element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML file:

```
<recursos>
    <recurso url="http://w3c.com">
        <descripcion>Consorcio W3C</descripcion>
        <tipo>externo</tipo>
        <idioma>ingles</idioma>
        <contenido>General</contenido>
        <unidad>Unidad 2</unidad>
    </recurso>
    <recurso url="http://html.com">
        <descripcion>Especificación HTML</descripcion>
        <tipo>externo</tipo>
        <idioma>castellano</idioma>
        <contenido>HTML</contenido>
        <version>4.01</version>
        <unidad>Unidad 3</unidad>
    </recurso>
</recursos>
```

I want to compare one "recurso"'s preceding sibling element "unidad" with the "unidad" of the current "recurso" to check if they're different.

I was trying:

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::recurso[position()=1]::unidad != unidad">
</xsl:if>
```

But I know it's horribly wrong :(
I hope you could help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Good first time question, BTW. Well-formatted, well-worded, with complete, but shortest-possible code sample. I wish more people would do it that way. :-)

Answer (score 39):

Almost correct.

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::recurso[1]/unidad != unidad">
</xsl:if>
```

The `::` is for axes, not for moving along a path ("making a location step"). In XPath terminology:

```
preceding-sibling::recurso[1]/unidad != unidad
'''''''''''''''''  ++++++++++ ++++++
                          ###
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~

'  = axis name       (optional, defaults to "child")
+  = node test       (required)
#  = predicate       (optional, for filtering)
~  = location step   (required at least once per select expression)
```

The `[1]` is a shorthand for `[position()=1]`.

The `child` axis is implicit in a location step, so this

```
preceding-sibling::recurso[1]/unidad != unidad
```

is equivalent to this:

```
preceding-sibling::recurso[1]/child::unidad != unidad
```