# preceding-sibling of current text node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, axes

I have this kind of XML :

```
<nav:objectList>
    <nav:item >
      <nav:attribute name="display">1</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="className">document.Document</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="title">item 1</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="getFileExtension">pdf</nav:attribute> 
    </nav:item>
    <nav:item >
      <nav:attribute name="display">2</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="className">video.Video</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="title">item 2</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="getFileExtension">mp4</nav:attribute> 
    </nav:item>
    <nav:item >
      <nav:attribute name="display">3</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="className">document.Document</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="title">item 3</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="getFileExtension">pdf</nav:attribute> 
    </nav:item>
    <nav:item >
      <nav:attribute name="display">4</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="className">video.Video</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="title">item 4</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="getFileExtension">mp4</nav:attribute> 
    </nav:item>
    <nav:item >
      <nav:attribute name="display">5</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="className">document.Document</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="title">item 5</nav:attribute> 
      <nav:attribute name="getFileExtension">pdf</nav:attribute> 
    </nav:item>
</nav:objectList>
```

I want to count all **document.Document** preceding the current document.Document.
(I don't want to count the video.Video)
For example, if i am on the 5, I want to return 2 and not 4.

It looks like the post :  [XSLT - Comparing preceding-sibling's elements with current's node element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990290/xslt-comparing-preceding-siblings-elements-with-currents-node-element)

I was actually trying (many things) like :

```
count(preceding-sibling::nav:attribute[@name='type.className']='com.arsdigita.cms.document.Document'
```

Thank's

Romain

Comment: @LarsH : You're right i want the full name com.arsdigita.cms.document.Document), i simplified the XML. Thanks to both of you !!
Your two answers are interesting, I'll try next monday (I can't test it before) and tell you wich one

Answer (score 1):

Change `preceding-sibling` to `preceding`, because the attributes you're trying to count are not siblings of the node you're trying to count from (they have different parents). Also you need to make a complete clause out of the `= 'document.Document'` part:

```
count(preceding::nav:attribute[@name='type.className'
                               and . = 'document.Document'])
```

(or maybe you want the full `'com.arsdigita.cms.document.Document'` in there?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with xslt, but I use xpath plenty. This yields a sequence of `nav:item` elements with the `document.Document` descendents:

```
//nav:item[nav:attribute[@name="className" and text()="document.Document"]]
```

And this run from one of those `nav:item` elements, will tell you how many similar elements precede it:

```
count(preceding-sibling::nav:item[nav:attribute[@name="className" and text()="document.Document"]])
```