# Selenium Xpath to find a table cells inside a div tag

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have the following HTML code that I need to check if text exists within a table cell:

```
<div class="background-ljus" id="AutoText">
  <table class="topAlignedCellContent">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>X1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>X2</td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Y1</td>
        <td>Y2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Z1</td>
        <td>Z2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have solved it like this:

```
By locator = getLocator(CommonConst.XPATH, "*//div[@" + type + "='" + anyName + "']");
  fluentWait(locator);

  WebElement div = getDriver().findElement(locator);
  List<WebElement> cells = div.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  for (WebElement cell : cells) {
    if (cell.getText().contains(cellText)) {
      foundit = true;
    }
  }
```

But i think its a bit slow because I need to do this several times. 
I tried to do this with only XPath but had no luck.

```
"*//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains[Text(), 'celltext']]"
"*//div[@id='AutoText']//table//tbody//tr[td//Text()[contains[., 'celltext']]"
```

Anyone have a suggestion about why my XPath isn't working?

Comment: Check out the note I added to my answer, it points out an important caveat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong:

```
*//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains[Text(), 'celltext']]
*//div[@id='AutoText']//table//tbody//tr[td//Text()[contains[., 'celltext']]
```

Correct (with shorter alternatives):

```
//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains(text(), 'celltext')]
//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains(., 'celltext')]

//div[@id='AutoText']/table/tbody/tr[td//text()[contains(., 'celltext')]
//div[@id='AutoText']/table/tbody/tr[td[contains(., 'celltext')]]
```

- `contains()` is a function
- `text()` needs to be lowercase
- predicates can be nested
- don't use `//` when you don't have to

**Note**

`.` refers to "this node" and, when given as an argument to a string function such as `contains()`, is the equivalent of `string(.)`. This, however, is not at all the same as `text()`.

`string(.)` creates the concatenation of all text nodes inside the current node, no matter how deeply nested. `text()` is a [*node test*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744783/18771) and by default selects only the direct children.

In other words, if the current node was `<td>foo <b>bar</b> baz</td>`, `contains(text(), 'bar')` would actually be false. (So would `contains(text(), 'baz')`, for a different reason.)

`contains(., 'bar')` on the other hand would return true, so would `contains(., 'baz')`.

Only when the current node contains nothing but a single text node, `text()` and `.` are equivalent. Most of the time, you will want to work with `.` instead of `text()`. Set up your predicates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath's are wrong. You should be using `text()` instead of `Text()`. Also `contains()` is a function with round braces and not square braces. Try this -

```
"//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains(text(), 'celltext')]"
"//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains(., 'celltext')]"
```

Or instead if you want all the child elements with the text to be displayed then use `.` instead of `text()`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks "//div[@id='AutoText']//td[contains(., 'celltext')]" solved the problem

Comment: @Calle if it solved your problem, kindly mark it as answer so that others find it helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dynamic xpath as well

```
//div[@id='AutoText']/table[1]//tbody/tr[1]/td
```

Now just replace 1 with i and use for loop to see if the element return any value or not