# Abbreviated syntax in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

What does `//olist/items` return?

Well, `//` is the abbreviation for `descendant-or-self::node()/` so it returns a set of nodes that are descendants of my context node. After that, it must have `olist` in its path.

`item` means `child::item` so it returns children of my context node (that is `//olist/`). So, in the end it returns item nodes, children of all children of my starting context node or one of its descndants that have `olist` in their path.

Right?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: what does `//olist/items` returns?

Comment: Do you have any sample XML that you are applying this XPath to?

Comment: No, I'm studing for my  IT exam and one question is "What does `//olist/items` stands for?". No XML.

Comment: Oh, you just want an explanation of the abbreviated syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> item means child::item so it returns children of my context node (that is //olist/). So, in the end it returns item nodes, children of all children of my starting context node or one of its descendent that have olist in their path.
>
> Right?

That's almost correct - not only must the `item` elements in the result set "`olist` in their path" (which I understand as: must be a descendant of `olist`) - they must be a direct child element of `olist`.

---

Then let us clear the confusion about the "root node":

When Matt Jones uses "root node" in his explanation of `//`, he does not mean the outermost element of his XML example. It is only by conincidence that the outermost element there is also called `root`.

The "root node" or "document node" is different from the outermost element of an XML document. The outermost element is physically present in your document, and all XML elements and attributes are inside it.

The document node is not visible in the document, it's an abstract concept that represents an entire XML document. All nodes in an XML document are descendants of the document node.

On the other hand, not all nodes are descendants of the outermost element: for instance, there could be processing instructions or comments outside the outermost element. But those processing instructions and comments are contained by the document node.

---

Now, `//` means either the context node or any of its descendants, as you know already. In this case, the *document node* will be the context of your path expression (if that's not what you want, prefix it with `.`: `.//`).

So the expression `//item` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::item` which means

> select any element node with the name `item` that is a child of a node anywhere in the XML structure

The parent of such an `item` element will either be the document node (in this case the `item` element will be the outermost element) or any element node.

---

In XPath 1.0, the abstract container for XML documents is called "root node", from XPath 2.0 onwards it is called "document node".

[XPath 1.0 Specification, Abbreviated Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)

["Document element and root node are often confused, but they are not the same thing"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744783/1987598)

Answer (score 0):

`//olist/items`

This XPath will return a collection of elements that have the name `items` that are child nodes of elements that have the name `olist` that are descendants of the root node of the XML document that you are querying.

In this sample XML here:

```
<root>
    <olist>
        <test/>
        <items value="A"/>
    </olist>
    <other>
        <inside>
            <items value="B"/>
            <olist>
                <items value="C"/>
            </olist>
        </inside>
    </other>
</root>
```

The `//olist/items` XPath will select the `items` elements with the `value` attributes of **A** and **C** - because they are child elements of `olist` elements.

It will not select the `items` element with the `value` attribute of **B** because that element does not have the required parent element of `olist`.

Syntactically, `//` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/` - on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant-or-self) it states

> The descendant-or-self axis indicates the context node and all of its descendants. Attribute and namespace nodes are not included - the parent of an attribute node is an element node, but attribute nodes are not the children of their parents.

`/olist` means `child::olist` - the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/child) definition of the child axis is

> The child axis indicates the children of the context node. If an XPath expression does not specify an axis, the child axis is understood by default. Since only the root node or element nodes have children, any other use will select nothing.

Comment: i cannot understand why root node ?

Comment: @bogALT - how much do you know about XML? If you don't know what a root node is, you have much to learn.

Comment: I just started learning. I know what a root node is and in the example you posted it works but what ifyou had other nodes between `<root>` and `<olist>` ? Lets say that the parent of `<olist>` was `<sales>` then this XPath would return a collection of elements that have the name items that are child nodes of elements that have the name olist that are descendants of the `<sales>` node of the XML document that you are querying. Is this correct?

Comment: @bogALT - look in my answer. You can see that I state that it selects two `items` elements, one at `/root/olist/items` and one at `/root/other/inside/olist/items`. I'm not going to write out a complete explanation of XPath, as this is what you should be trying to learn as part of your course. There is a vast amount of information on the internet about XPath - go and read that.

Comment: My misunderstandig is due to the fact that if you write `root` I guess is the "first" node of a document... the outermost. So If I have a document like `doc(stars.xml)/stars/star/filmograpy/2011/A/B` and i query '//2011/B' everything will start from the node `2011`. As it was the root node. Right?