# Why does node() XPath node type test return duplicates when used with SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I used this [examle xml document](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml) for practice. And I don't understand node() function in XPath. For example if I write:

```
$catalog = new SimpleXMLElement("cd.xml",null,true);
$elms = $catalog->xpath("//CD[23]/node()");

print_r($elms);
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24
                    [genre] => soul
                )

            [TITLE] => The dock of the bay
            [ARTIST] => Otis Redding
            [COUNTRY] => USA
            [COMPANY] => Stax Records
            [PRICE] => 7.90
            [YEAR] => 1968
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => The dock of the bay
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24
                    [genre] => soul
                )

            [TITLE] => The dock of the bay
            [ARTIST] => Otis Redding
            [COUNTRY] => USA
            [COMPANY] => Stax Records
            [PRICE] => 7.90
            [YEAR] => 1968
        ) ...
```

and so on, repeating CD[23] element after every child element. I tried many variations of this, and always get duplicates in some way. I don't understand why is that?

I tried editing xml document by removing new lines and spaces, so there are no text nodes in between the elements, and I get the result without duplicates. Is it the case that this was the way of xpath() method to represent those text nodes?

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744465/xpath-difference-between-node-and-text

Comment: I think part of the problem results from the simplification that SimpleXML involves, the `xpath` method returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement`s and with your path using `node()` to select any kind of child node of `CD[23]` in a pure XPath mapping you would get a node list or set containing text nodes and element nodes, it seems the designers of that API for PHP in the case of a text node selected return its parent element so for any text node child of `CD[23]` selected you get that element returned in the array. You might want to go with `CD[23]/*` to select any child elements.

Comment: Thanks, it is much clearer now

Comment: @MartinHonnen You should put that as an answer rather than a comment, because there's really not much more to say: SimpleXMLElements can't represent any node type other than element list, element, attribute list, and attribute, so everything else gets returned as its parent as you described.

Comment: @IMSoP, ok, I have morphed the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem results from the simplification that SimpleXML involves, the xpath method returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement`s and with your path using `node()` to select any kind of child node of `CD[23]` in a pure XPath mapping you would get a node list or set containing text nodes and element nodes, it seems the designers of that API for PHP in the case of a text node selected return its parent element so for any text node child of `CD[23]` selected you get that same parent element returned in the array. You might want to go with `CD[23]/*` to select any child elements.