# Regex to extract what's after <br> and stop at -

Tags: php, regex

code :

```
    <span class="_c1subtitle_c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>
```

i'm using regex to extract the text but i just can't figure out a pattern that will extract only 5132

i tried

`pattern3 = '/<span class="_c1subtitle_c1">(*?)<\/span>/s';`

Comment: You should consider reading **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)** before comitting too much resources into regex-based HTML parsers.,

Comment: Simply `preg_match('/<br>.*?(\d+)/', '<span class="_c1subtitle_c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>', $number)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, you could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get the second [text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744465/xpath-difference-between-node-and-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) node in the span.

The text node will give you `5132 - 0918`.

To get `5132` you could use explode and `-` as the delimiter.

```
// Html from your curl request.
$html = <<<HTML
    <span class="_c1subtitle_c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$secondTextNode = $xpath->query('//span[@class="_c1subtitle_c1"]/text()')->item(1);
if ($secondTextNode) {
    $result = explode("-", $secondTextNode->nodeValue)[0];
    echo $result;
}
```

That will give you:

> 5132

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/1kbG3)

Comment: @Timo What does not work? You pass the html which you receive with curl to `loadHTML` and then you get no results? So you get an error?

Comment: $cpage = curl('https://www.website.com');
$pattern4 = '/<span class="_c1subtitle_c1">(*?)<\/span>/s';
$data = preg_match_all($pattern4, $ccpage, $matches);

Comment: in the original website the numbers and text are separated by <br> like this : '<span class="_c1subtitle_c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>';

Comment: i wanna get the first number of that span for every user

Comment: @Timo Using `DOMDocument` avoids the need of using a regex and  `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match digits only you could try this pattern:

```
$s = '    <span class="_c1subtitle _c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>';
preg_match("/<br>\s*(\d+)\s*-/", $s, $matches);
$digits = $matches ? $matches[1] : NULL;
var_dump($digits);
```

The pattern [`"/<br>\s*(\d+)\s*-/"`](https://regex101.com/r/DHvwDN/1) will match any sequence of digits between the first `<br>` and the next `-`. Note that leading and trailing whitespace will not be included in the match because `\s*` consumes it outside of the capture group `(\d+)`.

To capture everything verbatim between the `<br>` and the first `-` you could use [`"/<br>(.+?)-/"`](https://regex101.com/r/kaRQB8/1/) as the pattern:

```
preg_match("/<br>(.+?)-/", $s, $matches);
$text = $matches ? $matches[1] : NULL;
var_dump($text);
```

which will show that the whitespace has also been captured.

Answer (score 0):

parsing data from html is not really the best candidate for regex.
you should use html parsers for that.

But if you still want to do it with regex, you can use something like this `/<br>(.*?)-/`

what this does it searches for text `<br>`, and captures anything up to the first "-" sign into `$matches[1]`.

If you only want to capture numbers there is a better way to do that.

```
$text = ' <span class="_c1subtitle _c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>';
$result = preg_match('/<br>(.*?)-/', $text, $matches);

var_dump($result);//1 - if match was found, 0 otherwise
var_dump($matches);//array, 0 - full matched string, 1 - match inside group
var_dump(trim($matches[1]));//5132 this is what you want in your case
```

for more information i would recommend reading:
[dom parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) and [preg match documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: i forgot to mention that this is a curl related code i'm extracting data from a website so i basically don't have the original code i just know the tags

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly

```
$text = '<span class="_c1subtitle_c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>';
$match= preg_match("/\s\d+\s(?=\-)/",$text);
echo $match;
```

**\s** matches any whitespace character

**\d+** matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

**\-** matches the character - literally

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simply `preg_match('/<br>.*?(\d+)/', '<span class="_c1subtitle_c1">Name<br> 5132 - 0918</span>', $number)`

This will get you started in the right direction.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/some.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/<br>.*?(\d+)/', $html, $numbers);
print_r($numbers); # You will see your matches
```

Comment: i like this pattern but how can i use it with curl ?