# Extract field from XML Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an issue as I never done that before.

I have an SQL table with the following :

```
ID int;
xml_record xml;
```

The xml record is looking like that :

```
<root xml:space="preserve" id="XXX">
<c1>Data1</c1>
<c2>Data2</c2>
<c3>Data3</c3>
...
<cn>DataN</cn>
</root>
```

However I tried to use the following query with no success (return null) :

```
SELECT xml_record.value('c1[1]','varchar(50)') as value_c1
FROM myTable
```

The problem might come from the "space" but not sure.

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to fix the expression:

```
SELECT xml_record.value('(/root/c1)[1]','varchar(50)') AS value_c1
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT 
   xml_record.value
   ( '(/root/c1/text())[1])', 
  'varchar(50)') as value_c1
   FROM myTable
```

> else remove the first xml line

Comment: Thank you I'll try as soon as I can. But actually the record is a big line. How could I get rid of the first line ?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Why do you double the slash before `//c1`? This will trigger a *deep search*, which is not needed here... Furthermore you should pick [`text()` instead of `node()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744783/5089204)

Comment: @Shnugo my bad actually i referred from a different article got your point now `//c1 ` will trigger for all c1s as you correctly said as deep search and wasnt aware that ` `text()` was there to select text inside the tag. thanks for the help :)