# Bind xPath nodes to java Bean objects

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb

I have two kind of files that can contain:

1. A list of objects
2. A single object

Example file for list of objects:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getBeanListResponse xmlns:ns2="namespace">
            <beanObject>
                <fieldA>valueA</fieldA>
                <fieldB>valueB</fieldB>
                <fieldC>valueC</fieldC>
            </beanObject>
            <beanObject>
                <fieldA>valueD</fieldA>
                <fieldB>valueE</fieldB>
                <fieldC>valueF</fieldC>
            </beanObject>
            <beanObject>
                <fieldA>valueG</fieldA>
                <fieldB>valueH</fieldB>
                <fieldC>valueI</fieldC>
            </beanObject>
        </ns2:getBeanListResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Example file for single object:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getBeanResponse xmlns:ns2="namespace">
            <beanObject>
                <fieldA>value1</fieldA>
                <fieldB>value2</fieldB>
                <fieldC>value3</fieldC>
            </beanObject>
        </ns2:getBeanResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I use `XPathExpression` to retrieve the object(s) and `JaxB` to convert the xml data into java objects. For the file with a list of Objects i used the expression

```
//beanObject
```

and had no problems so far.. `JaxB` successufully translates that xml data into java objects. However I do something wrong when parsing a single object.. I used the same xPathExpression but something goes wrong. Here is the function that is used for the list of objects:

```
public Object getNodeListValues(String expression) {
    NodeList resultNodes;
    
    try {
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xpath.compile(expression);
        resultNodes = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BeanObject.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        
        for (int i=0; i<resultNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            BeanObject obj = (BeanObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(resultNodes.item(i));
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

but I'm not sure on how to process a single bean object.. I tried with this function:

```
public Object getNodeValue(String expression) {
        Node resultNode = null;
        try {
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = xpath.compile(expression);
            resultNode = (Node) xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
            return resultNode.getText();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

but that gives me an exception saying that the cast is not possible:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.dom4j.Node
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744465/xpath-difference-between-node-and-text#:%7E:text=node()%20matches%20any%20node,*%20matches%20any%20element%20node) I guess that the node result here is the `text node` which is the `\n`    part, but it's not clear to me why the list of items works and this function doesn't.. How can I get all the values of that xml bean? Also assume that I don't know the structure or fields of the objects in the xml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to cast to `org.dom4j.Node`, instead of `org.w3c.dom.Node`. Change your `import` statements or use the fully qualified class name.

**Edit:** Since you probably don't need DOM4j in this class you should have:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
```

in the preamble and your method should be:

```java
    public String getNodeValue(String expression) {
        Node resultNode = null;
        try {
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = xpath.compile(expression);
            resultNode = (Node) xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
            // DOM4j and DOM have similar methods, but with different names.
            return resultNode.getTextContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to cast to `org.dom4j.Node`, trying to cast to `org.w3c.dom.Node` gives a type mismatch error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.w3c.dom.Node to org.dom4j.Node`

Comment: Yes, that is the problem: there should be no `org.dom4j` in the `getNodeValue` function. Both the `resultNode` variable and the cast should be to the W3C interface `org.w3c.dom.Node`. In Java many classes have the same simple name, but you usually use only one of them.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked. Didn't know about this difference, guess I'll have to look it up.

Comment: It's an easy bug to miss, the editors take care of managing the `import` statements (and Eclipse's first choice is usually the wrong one :-) ). [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is a standard interface and in Java has an implementation embedded into the JRE (a copy of Xerces). [DOM4j](https://dom4j.github.io/) is an external library, which you probably have as a dependency of Hibernate. When in doubt choose DOM.