# XPATH - Why the parentheses in text() function

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

This might sound like a pretty simple question but I wasn't able to find answers anywhere.
What's the point of the parentheses when using the ***text()*** function in XPATHs ?

Why can't I simply use **//div[text='myText']** instead of **//div[text()='myText']** ?

Is it possible to pass some kind of parameters to the function somehow ?

Thanks

Comment: Well innovative question in a while (+1)

Comment: text() is not a function, but a node-type. I suppose it is so to distinguish a element with the name text

Comment: Technically it’s a “node test”. Regarding parameters, the processing-instruction() node test does take an optional parameter. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests

Comment: A good discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744465/xpath-difference-between-node-and-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` without parentheses is a name test matching `text` elements. For example, an element like

```
<div>
    <text>myText</text>
</div>
```

would be matched by `//div[text='myText']`. So the parens are needed for disambiguation. `text()` is a node type test matching text nodes. It is not a function. For example, you can also use it with an axis like `descendant::text()`.

Comment: Learned something new today

Comment: it won't work , `//span[text="Stack Overflow"]` , `//span[text()="Stack Overflow"]`

Comment: try both in this page , you won't get any span tag with the first approach

Comment: Correct answer. In retrospect, it might have been better to use a different syntactic marker, for example `%text` or `#text`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value

Browsers support only xpath 1.0.

So as per this documentation, there are 7 node types:

> 1. The root node comes from the document information item. The children
>    of the root node come from the children and children - comments
>    properties.
> 2. An element node comes from an element information item. The children
>    of an element node come from the children and children - comments
>    properties. The attributes of an element node come from the
>    attributes property. The namespaces of an element node come from the
>    in-scope namespaces property. The local part of the expanded-name of
>    the element node comes from the local name property. The namespace
>    URI of the expanded-name of the element node comes from the
>    namespace URI property. The unique ID of the element node comes from
>    the children property of the attribute information item in the
>    attributes property that has an attribute type property equal to ID.
> 3. An attribute node comes from an attribute information item. The
>    local part of the expanded-name of the attribute node comes from the
>    local name property. The namespace URI of the expanded-name of the
>    attribute node comes from the namespace URI property. The
>    string-value of the node comes from concatenating the character code
>    property of each member of the children property.
> 4. A text node comes from a sequence of one or more consecutive
>    character information items. The string-value of the node comes from
>    concatenating the character code property of each of the character
>    information items.
> 5. A processing instruction node comes from a processing instruction
>    information item. The local part of the expanded-name of the node
>    comes from the target property. (The namespace URI part of the
>    expanded-name of the node is null.) The string-value of the node
>    comes from the content property. There are no processing instruction
>    nodes for processing instruction items that are children of document
>    type declaration information item.
> 6. A comment node comes from a comment information item. The
>    string-value of the node comes from the content property. There are
>    no comment nodes for comment information items that are children of
>    document type declaration information item.
> 7. A namespace node comes from a namespace declaration information
>    item. The local part of the expanded-name of the node comes from the
>    prefix property. (The namespace URI part of the expanded-name of the
>    node is null.) The string-value of the node comes from the namespace
>    URI property.

in version 1 all this nodes expect attrubutes node are accessed as nodetype()=value

eg comment()=value, text()=value etc.

For attribute node type the value is accessed as @attribute=value

In Xpath 3.0 even attrubute node is changed to attribute() , but as browsers have stopped supporting xpath and is concentrating on css , all browsers supports only xpath 1.0.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#node-tests

> node() matches any node.
>
> text() matches any text node.
>
> comment() matches any comment node.
>
> namespace-node() matches any namespace node.
>
> element() matches any element node.
>
> schema-element(person) matches any element node whose name is person
> (or is in the substitution group headed by person), and whose type
> annotation is the same as (or is derived from) the declared type of
> the person element in the in-scope element declarations.
>
> element(person) matches any element node whose name is person,
> regardless of its type annotation.
>
> element(person, surgeon) matches any non-nilled element node whose
> name is person, and whose type annotation is surgeon or is derived
> from surgeon.
>
> element(*, surgeon) matches any non-nilled element node whose type
> annotation is surgeon (or is derived from surgeon), regardless of its
> name.
>
> attribute() matches any attribute node.
>
> attribute(price) matches any attribute whose name is price, regardless
> of its type annotation.
>
> attribute(*, xs:decimal) matches any attribute whose type annotation
> is xs:decimal (or is derived from xs:decimal), regardless of its name.
>
> document-node() matches any document node.
>
> document-node(element(book)) matches any document node whose content
> consists of a single element node that satisfies the kind test
> element(book), interleaved with zero or more comments and processing
> instructions.