# Getting XML sections using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml(TEI) structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="../schema/tei_color.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="../schema/tei_color.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
    </teiHeader>
    <text xml:id="Z_1822-02-20_k" xml:lang="ger">
        <body>
            <div>
                <div rendition="simple:half-broken">
                    <pb n="46r" facs="#Z_1822-02-20_k_A_0001"/>
                    <cb rendition="simple:column-left"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <cb rendition="simple:column-right"/>
                    <p>
                        <handShift scribeRef="#Z_1822-02-20_k_scrb_1_t"/>Auf
                        <pb n="46v" facs="#Z_1822-02-20_k_A_0002"/>
                        <hi rendition="simple:italic">Heliostaten</hi> von dem Herrn Geheimen<lb/>Post-Rath
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

Using XPath how do I get pb elements including xml content thereunder.

Comment: This isn't valid XML.  Please at least provide a minimal example that is actually valid XML.  For example, what are those "some xml content" text nodes enclosed within?  What XPath expressions have you tried so far?

Comment: I just edited the code and reduce it to get a real example. I am new to XPath and tried //tei:pb for example.

Comment: there is no content in the <pb> element other than the "n" and "facs" attributes. If you are referring to <cb>, that is a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language where you use xpath, you can use 2 different XPath's like these:

```
//pb
```

and

```
//pb/following-sibling::*
```

Or if you can reuse //pb in a variable just use that variable extended with XPath:

```
./following-sibling::*
```

Or all in one using the union operator `|`:

```
//pb | //pb/following-sibling::*
```

If the xml content thereunder could be just plain text, you should use:

```
//pb | //pb/following-sibling::node()
```

The `node()` wil select all nodes including `text()`-nodes as well as `element()`-nodes. For more info on node() see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744783/3710053).

Comment: Did this answered your question?