# parsing XPath expression understanding EBNF production rules

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, w3c, ebnf

I have a beginners question regarding the W3C specification (EBNF notation) of XPath expressions. The specification can be found at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/. In particular I have a question about understanding the following expression:

```
(//attribute::name | //attribute::id)[starts-with(string(self::node()), "be") or starts-with(string(self::node()), "1")]
```

This appears to be a valid expression. I verified using http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html with the following XML document:

```
<documentRoot>
<!-- Test data -->
<?xc value="2" ?>
<parent name="data" >
   <child id="1"  name="alpha" >Some Text</child>
   <child id="2"  name="beta" >
      <grandchild id="2.1"  name="beta-alpha" ></grandchild>
      <grandchild id="2.2"  name="beta-beta" ></grandchild>
   </child>
   <pet name="tigger"  type="cat" >
      <data>
         <birthday month="sept"  day="19" ></birthday>
         <food name="Acme Cat Food" ></food>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <pet name="Fido"  type="dog" >
      <description>
         Large dog!
      </description>
      <data>
         <birthday month="feb"  day="3" ></birthday>
         <food name="Acme Dog Food" ></food>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <rogue name="is this real?" >
      <data>
         Hates dogs!
      </data>
   </rogue>
   <child id="3"  name="gamma"  mark="yes" >
      <!-- A comment -->
      <description>
         Likes all animals - especially dogs!
      </description>
      <grandchild id="3.1"  name="gamma-alpha" >
         <![CDATA[ Some non-parsable character data ]]>
      </grandchild>
      <grandchild id="3.2"  name="gamma-beta" ></grandchild>
   </child>
</parent>
</documentRoot>
```

This gives me the following results:

```
Attribute='id="1"'
Attribute='name="beta"'
Attribute='name="beta-alpha"'
Attribute='name="beta-beta"'
```

It is not clear to me which sequence of EBNF productions would produce the above query.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to correctly represent this but `Expr >>> FilterExpr Predicate`:

```
Expr > OrExpr > AndExpr > EqualityExpr > RelationalExpr > AdditiveExpr > MultiplicativeExpr > UnaryExpr > UnionExpr > PathExpr > FilterExpr > FilterExpr Predicate
```

gives you the 2 parts:

- the filter `(//attribute::name | //attribute::id)`
- and the predicate `[starts-with(string(self::node()), "be") or starts-with(string(self::node()), "1")]`

**`(//attribute::name | //attribute::id)`**

```
FilterExpr > PrimaryExpr > '(' Expr ')'
Expr > OrExpr > AndExpr > EqualityExpr > RelationalExpr > AdditiveExpr > MultiplicativeExpr > UnaryExpr > UnionExpr > UnionExpr '|' PathExpr
```

gives you `//attribute::name` and `//attribute::id`

**`//attribute::name` and `//attribute::id`**

```
PathExpr > LocationPath > AbsoluteLocationPath > AbbreviatedAbsoluteLocationPath > '//' RelativeLocationPath
RelativeLocationPath > Step > AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate*
    - AxisSpecifier > AxisName '::'
        - AxisName > 'attribute'
    - NodeTest > NameTest
```

`NameTest` being `name` and `id`

**Predicate `[starts-with(string(self::node()), "be") or starts-with(string(self::node()), "1")]`**

```
Predicate > '[' PredicateExpr ']' > Expr > OrExpr > OrExpr 'or' AndExpr
    - OrExpr > AndExpr
    - AndExpr > EqualityExpr > RelationalExpr > AdditiveExpr > MultiplicativeExpr > UnaryExpr > UnionExpr > PathExpr > FilterExpr > PrimaryExpr > FunctionCall > FunctionName '(' ( Argument ( ',' Argument )* )? ')'
        Argument > Expr
```

`FunctionName` being `starts-with`, first argument being another `FunctionCall` (`string` function), second argument being `Literal`s (via `PathExpr > FilterExpr > PrimaryExpr`), "be" and "1".

Finally, **self::node()** comes from:

```
RelativeLocationPath > Step > AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate*
    - AxisSpecifier > AxisName '::'
        - AxisName > 'attribute'
    - NodeTest > NodeType '(' ')'
```

`NodeType` being 'node'

Comment: Great!! Now I get it. Thank you so much. I totally missed the FilterExpression rule. I was stuck with "Step = AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate". Very quick and good reply!!

Answer (score 3):

Break-down:

```
(                        # group
  //attribute::name      #   the long form of //@name
  |                      #   union
  //attribute::id        #   the long form of //@id 
)                        # group end
[                        # predicate (think "where")
  starts-with(           #   returns true or false
    string(              #     returns a string
      self::node()       #        the long form of "."
    ),                   #     )
    "be"                 #     a string literal
  )                      #   )
  or                     #   logical operator
  starts-with(           #   ...idem
    string(              #
      self::node()       #
    ),                   #
    "1"                  #
  )                      #
]                        # end predicate
```

So the expression is a rather unnecessarily verbose version of

```
(//@name | //@id)[starts-with(., "be") or starts-with(., "1")]
```

selecting all attributes named `"name"` or `"id"` whose values begin with `"be"` or `"1"`

I'm not sure why you want the EBNF productions for this (homework, I presume), but understanding the expression itself might help you with it.

A few extra notes:

- `attribute::` designates the attribute *axis*.
- Axes can precede any [*node test*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990290/xslt-comparing-preceding-siblings-elements-with-currents-node-element/2990317#2990317) (the default axis always is `child::`).
- The `self::` axis is special, it contains only the node in question. The short form of `self::node()` is the dot (`.`). The implication is that if the node in question is a `<foo>` node,  `self::foo` will match it, while `self::bar` will not.
- `//` is the shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`
- The `string()` function is redundant because `starts-with()` will convert its arguments to string implicitly anyway.
- The union operator joins two node sets. Nodes that appear in both sets are not duplicated in the result.
- Predicates are applied to each node in a node set, effectively filtering it.

Comment: To be pedantic `//` is a shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, not `/descendant::` (true, in many cases the distinction doesn't matter, but there are certain cases where it's critical, e.g. to make `//@foo` well-defined, or the difference between `//*[1]` and `/descendant::*[1]`)

Comment: @Ian Thanks, will correct this! — To be even more pedantic, `//` is the shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::` - nothing less, but nothing more, too. `node()` is not part if it. :)

Comment: No, `//` means precisely `/descendant-or-self::node()/` including the leading and trailing slashes ([XPath spec §2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)).  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to say things like `//@foo` as that would be `/descendant::attribute::foo` (you can't use two axes in the same location step).

Comment: Hm. Apparently there was an error in my logic until now (all these years!! \*howl\*). You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing this out to me.