# How to correctly use `XPath` locators, such as `parent`, `child`, following-sibling`?

Tags: html, xpath

I have some form:

```
<div class="form_item--2c8WB">
    <label>
        <span class="label--2VxxL required--2nkmI">
            "Text"
            ::after
        </span> 
        <br> 
        <input type="password" name="newPasswordRepeat" autocomplete="new-password" 
               aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" 
               aria-errormessage="vee_Text2">
    </label> 
    <div class="errors--qVgtm">
        <div>Text3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to find path to `Text3` text element, but exactly via `input` section:

My way:

```
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']/../../div/div
```

The path is valid, but it is a long way to go and I want to use the `follow-sibling` command. But I can't do that

For example, I'm trying to use the `parent::` path:

```
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']/parent::
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']::parent::
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']::parent
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']/parent
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']/::parent
```

No one from this order not working, only

```
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']/..
```

Also I cannot use `following-sibling`, but in this case another way (`..`, `.`) does not exist.

- How to correctly use `XPath` locators such as `parent`, `child`, following-sibling`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always `axis::node_test` (compare this [answer where I explain various XPath terms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2990317/18771)).

For example

- `parent::div` selects the parent node **if** it's a `<div>` (that's the node test).
- `ancestor::div` selects all (!) ancestor nodes that are `<div>`s.
- `following-sibling::div` selects all (!) following siblings that are `<div>`s.

Most of the time there is no guarantee that only a single node is selected. Therefore it's sensible to also have some sort of `[predicate]` that narrows down the selection to prevent false positives - for example we could verify the `@class` attribute.

```
//input[@name='newPasswordRepeat']/parent::label/following-sibling::div[starts-with(@class, 'errors')]/div
```

Of course `parent::label` can be shortened to `..` if we don't care what kind of element the parent is.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than select a target and have to traverse up to a parent, consider using a predicate on the parent in the first place:

```
//label[input/@name='newPasswordRepeat']/following-sibling::*[1]/div
```

will select the `div` child of the element immediately following the `label` which contains the targeted `input` element.  No `parent::` axis is required.